# python audiotools pcm.read() reading only 88200 frames instead of 13397580

Tags: python, audio, frames, pcm

I am using Python Audiotools library to access raw data of a song. When I convert the `.flac` to `.wv` and then `to_pcm()`, and do a `pcm.read()`, it shows me only the first `88200` frames of the song instead of the entire `13397580` frames. These frames that it shows are correct. I cross-checked against Audacity. Could anyone help me as to why this could be happening? I am sampling at `44.1kHz`. So `88200` frames means it shows me exactly the first `2` seconds.

Here is my code

```
import os
from audiotools import *

files = os.listdir('./') 
stream = open(files[3])
wave = stream.convert("sample.wv",WavPackAudio)
pcm_wave = wave.to_pcm()
print len(pcm_wave.read())

for frame in frames:
  print frame,
  print "\t",
```

Comment: From the ```audiotools``` [docs](http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/programming/audiotools.html#audiotools.PCMReader) it looks like you should provide a number of frames when using the ```read()``` method and that it may return an unexpected number of frames. If you call ```read()``` again does it return the next 2 seconds of data?

Comment: It gives the same result if I give it the number of frames to read. And no, calling read() again does not give the next set of frames. It gives the same frames again.